# Do ante- and anti- come from the same word in Latin?

Tags: etymology

Do ante- and anti- come from the same word in Latin?

Comment: You can look up the etymology here for [ante-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ante-) and [anti-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/anti-#etymonline_v_13525). The first is from Latin, the second is from Greek, and both have very different meanings. If you go far enough back to Proto-Indo-European, the entries described seem to suggest these have a common ancestor.

Answer (score 3):

No. For a start, the website Etymology Online suggests that they aren't both Latin in origin. [*Ante-*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ante-) is Latin, but [*Anti-*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/anti-) is of Greek origin, although it was probably assimilated into Latin.

They were different in meaning in their original form, and they don't have the same meaning in English, either:

- Ante means *before* (in the sense of being 'in front of' something).
- Anti means *against* (in the sense of being opposite, or opposed to).

For example, *antemeridian* means 'before noon', but *antimeridian* means the opposite side of the world from the centre of the prime meridian, Greenwich, England.

I'm guessing that maybe your reason for thinking that they might have some shared etymology is due to words like *antipasto*, which is a borrowed word from Italian and means a small course *before* the main meal. But that's a matter of how the Latin 'ante' developed in Italian, and not really a question about English.

Comment: Although some words do have both prefixes [for different reasons]. Meridian, for instance - antemeridian is before noon, but antimeridian is the opposite side of the world from Greenwich ;)

Comment: @DoneWithThis. That's a much better example than my convoluted one - I've incorporated that into my answer, thank you.

Comment: No worries. Welcome. It just popped into my head as I was reading your answer.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. `antimeridian` (one word) is either a meridian at 180° from another, or the meridian opposite the prime (Greenwich) meridian; `Ante meridiem`, two words) normally abbreviated a.m., Latin for "before midday".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/antemeridian